# How can I do debounceTime but with the first value

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a event stream, but I need to detect when the event started and when it finished.

I hope this marble diagram will help

[image]

For example, when you press the key, **(S)** was triggered. While I'm holding the key down, no events occur. But when I release the key, after 50ms event **(E)** are triggering

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be an approach:

```js
const customOperator = src$ => {
  let hasSentStartEvent = false;

  return src$.pipe(
    debounce(
      () => !hasSentStartEvent
        ? (hasSentStartEvent = true, timer(0, 50).pipe(skip(1), tap(() => hasSentStartEvent = false)))
        : timer(50).pipe(tap(() => hasSentStartEvent = false))
    ),
    map((_, idx) => idx % 2 === 0 ? 'S' : 'E'),
  )
}

src$.pipe(
  customOperator
).subscribe();
```

I decided it was a case for a custom operator since this approach requires maintaining an internal state in order to determine **which stage** the `debounce` operator is at. In our situation, the only state we're having is `hasSentStartEvent`, which indicates whether the start event(denoted in the diagram with `S`) has been sent.

The `debounce` operator takes in a function which returns an observable. Whether the returned observable is subscribed or not depends on the source(i.e `src$`). If the source hasn't emitted anything, then the `debounce`'s inner observable won't be subscribed.
As soon as **the first value** is sent by the source, the inner observable resulted from invoking the provided callback function will be subscribed. This is also the case when the `hasSentStartEvent` variable is `false` and thus the first *if branch* will be chosen. So, the `S` event will be sent and `hasSentStartEvent` will be set to true.
If the next emitted values by the source come before `50ms` pass(i.e the timer's value), then the second *if branch* will be chosen, since the internal state of our custom operator indicates that the `S` event has already been sent. It is also important to mention here that every time the source emits, the inner observable will be unsubscribed(if it's active) and a new observable will be created by invoking the callback function and it will subscribed.
Finally, when `50ms` pass without the source emitting any values, the `E`(i.e *end*) event will be sent and `hasSentStartEvent` will be set to `false`.

---

### EDIT

On second thought, it looks like the `debounce`'s inner observable will be [automatically unsubscribed if it emits a value](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/debounce.ts#L76). So, the solution could also be:

```js
const customOperator = src$ => {
  let hasSentStartEvent = false;

  return src$.pipe(
    debounce(
      () => !hasSentStartEvent
        // Just emitting a value immediately.
        ? (hasSentStartEvent = true, of(null))
        : timer(50).pipe(tap(() => hasSentStartEvent = false))
    ),
    map((_, idx) => idx % 2 === 0 ? 'S' : 'E'),
  )
}

src$.pipe(
  customOperator
).subscribe();
```

Comment: An elegant solution, but if the first event has emitted and second event hasn't emitted `timer(50)` wasn't executed and I won't get a result that the stream is paused

Comment: @EvgenyNaumov so you're referring to the case where only one value is emitted? In that case, you would expect one `S` event and after `50ms` an `E` event, right?

Comment: yes, that what I expect